# Is it safe to cover LEDs on my fans with electric tape?

Tags: led, security

Just wondering.  Some of these LEDs on my Antec 1200 case are kind of annoying since the computer is in my bedroom.  Is it safe to cover these LEDs with electric tape?  I've already done so for awhile but when I put my finger on those covered LEDs I find the tape rather warm to the touch.

Is there a safer way (short of removing the LEDs, which I don't think I will be able to easily do) to "black out" these LEDs, but not in such a permanent manner?  I've seen suggestions to use a sharpie to color over them, but I find that solution to be rather undesirable.

Comment: Put a large cardboard box (with air holes on the non lighted sides) around the case!

Comment: **Pro Tip** Simply buy fans that don't have LEDs in them, or don't buy a computer with stupid lights.  They don't do anything useful.  I have never understood why people wanted the stupid lighted fans in the first place.

Comment: @Zoredache - I've always hated LEDs - I bought the case because I wanted it for the features the case provided and the good airflow it has.  I hate LEDs in my case unless they're for purely functional purposes, such as HDD lights and POST codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the standard black electric tape, you can proceed. There are three risks you can think of:

- The tape could melt/ignite: **no**. This would require a temperature of between 100 and 260 degrees Celsius depending on the tape brand. If your rig reaches such a temperature ever, you have bigger problems than the tape.
- The fans can be damaged: **yes**. Since the LEDs are on the fans, the tape's edges could be hit by the fan's wings if cut too long. Avoid this, this will likely cause some damage to the fans, not to mention an horrible noise.
- The airflow could be reduced : **yes**. Avoid obstructing any vents. This could lead to a more problematic overheating, not in terms of the tape getting hot, but in terms of eletrical components not being cooled enough.

Comment: Spray paint goes a long way in blacking out led's.

Answer (score 1):

I always just take a small set of snips or clippers and clip the leads going to the led's. This method keeps the LED in place as not to affect air flow in any way, but kills the super annoying lights.

Comment: If you don't clip off too much you can solder the ends back together if you reconsider.